# Cannot make compass + guard + sass to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass, compass-sass, guard

Rails 3.0.9.

In Gemfile:

```
gem 'compass-rails' (1.0.1)
gem 'sass' (3.0.19)
...

group :development, :test do
  gem 'guard' (1.0.3)
  gem 'guard-sass' (0.6.0)
  ...
end
```

In this configuration the error is:

```
ERROR: Sass > Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass.
              Load paths:
                /var/www/inbox/public
                /var/www/inbox/public/images
                /var/www/inbox/public/images/intro
                ...
```

(generally I can see that the path to compass is missing (i.e. `...ruby-1.9.3-p194-perf/gems/compass-0.12.1/frameworks/compass/stylesheets` is **not** there), so somehow compass is not being loaded and I don't know what to do to make it load.

When I trade `guard-sass` for `guard-compass` the error is:

```
ERROR: Rails.root is nil! (RuntimeError)
/home/jkl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194-perf/gems/sass-3.1.19/lib/sass/util.rb:370:in `rails_root'
/home/jkl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194-perf/gems/sass-3.1.19/lib/sass/plugin/rails.rb:11:in `default_options'
/home/jkl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194-perf/gems/sass-3.1.19/lib/sass/plugin/configuration.rb:33:in `options'
/home/jkl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194-perf/gems/sass-3.1.19/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:38:in `initialize'
/home/jkl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194-perf/gems/sass-3.1.19/lib/sass/plugin.rb:63:in `new'
/home/jkl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194-perf/gems/sass-3.1.19/lib/sass/plugin.rb:63:in `compiler'
/home/jkl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194-perf/gems/sass-3.1.19/lib/sass/plugin.rb:120:in `options'
...
```

I want this for `guard-livereload` to work properly whenever I update a `.sass` file.

Note, that normally compass works properly. Upon page refresh new CSS is being generated from SASS files.

Comment: tried prefixing with `bundle exec` or using my gem `rubygems-bundler`?

Comment: I'm running a zsh addon which prefixes every rake/guard/etc. command with "bundle exec" if Gemfile is found (https://github.com/pjg/dotfiles/blob/master/.zsh/bundler/bundler.plugin.zsh). So no bundler problems here :) I think that this is some kind of ordering problem, i.e. guard-sass is loaded before compass-rails has a chance of being loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `guard-sass` hardcodes SASS import paths only to subdirectories of the current directory (see https://github.com/hawx/guard-sass/blob/ac65c06fb0ea237713197730196d30ac47840bbf/lib/guard/sass.rb#L20 in the latest version 0.6.0) thus importing SASS from Compass is impossible (compass paths are not in the load paths of SASS).

The workaround for that is to override the `:load_paths` setting. Here's how I do it:

```
  guard 'sass', 
    :input => 'app/assets/stylesheets', 
    :output => 'public/stylesheets', 
    :load_paths => Dir.glob(File.join(Gem.dir, "gems", "compass*", "frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets")) + Dir.glob(File.join(Gem.dir, "gems", "compass*", "frameworks/compass/stylesheets"))
```

Or just upgrade to version 0.7+, where the above should be no longer necessary.

Comment: I'm having Rails.root is nil! errors as well with latest guard and guard-sasss...

Comment: Thanks a lot, Paweł! That does the trick for me. Even though I'm using compass 0.12.2 I experienced the error.

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed guard-sass on my Rails 3.0.9 project and encountered the same issue. The answer Pawel provided did not help me. Then, I realized that I don't need to use guard on my development server, I just need to make sure that it is installed on my local machine when I am working on styles and scripts so my Sass will become CSS and then compressed CSS (Jammit).

What I've done is isolate my guard gems in a group in my Gemfile like:

```
group :guard do
  gem 'rb-fsevent',   :require => false if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/i # Installs fsevent if on a Mac
  gem "sass",         "~> 3.2.1"
  gem 'guard-sass',   "~> 1.0.0"
  gem 'guard-jammit'
end
```

Then I can start up my rails application in a terminal window, and guard in another terminal.

Comment: This might be the proper way of solving that. I'll be sure to check it out.